# How to create only one table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem with creating tables in data base in Hibernate. In cfg of hibernate I have:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Thats ok, but I want to remove all data from only ONE single table.

When I will change cfg to:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

All of tables will be recreated and that's in not what i want.

Comment: What do you mean by one database? Hibernate default configuration always uses one database. What did you do different?

Comment: Terminology.... u meant tables, no?

Comment: I've edited my post sorry :)

Comment: are you looking for [cascade-delete](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean a single table in a database? because from my understanding; when configuring hiberate, we provide just a single database connection to it using the hibernate.connection.url property, a username and password etc. you can actually drop a single table in your database using session.createSQLQuery("DROP TABLE table_name").executeUpdate();... so i am still trying to get your point

Comment: I've edited my post sorry :) I want to create single table without any datas inside.

Comment: have you created your persistence.xml file? hibernate works with persistent unit. see help here for a quick start http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/ http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-database-table-using-hibernate/28269